# Immediately Invoked Function Expression without any private variable nor return value?

Tags: javascript

I was reading through the javascript design patterns book and came across the code below, while reading "The Command Pattern". I've been trying to understand why this code is wrapped around an anonymous function which is immediately invoked, especially since there is no other private variables to be closured with. How is this different from just declaring CarManager as an object literal?

```
(function(){

  var CarManager = {

    // request information
    requestInfo: function( model, id ){
      return 'The information for ' + model + ' with ID ' + id + ' is foobar';
    },

    // purchase the car
    buyVehicle: function( model, id ){
      return 'You have successfully purchased Item ' + id + ', a ' + model;
    },

    // arrange a viewing
    arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
      return 'You have successfully booked a viewing of ' + model + ' ( ' + id + ' ) ';
    }

  };

})();
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is done so `CarManager` doesn't pollute the global scope.

Comment: Looks like a special case of no-op. Nice way to waste computer cycles.

Comment: @elclanrs - I thought so too. Then I realized that `CarManager` is never used.

Comment: For reference, here's a web version of that section: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript

Comment: `CarManager` **is** defined as object literal... I assume it's just an example.

Comment: And as @AaditMShah mentioned, CarManager is never used inside the anon function scope. I thought there must be a reason, since this is a well recognized book on advanced javascript, but can't figure it out...

Comment: @FelixKling what I meant was--what difference does it make if you just scrap the first line and the last line?

Comment: @Vlad in this exact case, based on that exact code -- nothing (except that in one CarManager is useless, and is never used before falling out of scope). But in practical-application, there are plenty of uses for this, for different reasons.  The problem with the demonstration isn't that there isn't a return value -- it's that there isn't a clearly-defined "out", somewhere, be it a return, assignment to a property of a passed-in object, or assignment to `window["CarMaker"]` or similar.

Comment: @Norguard Thank you for this, I was totally confused about this part and your comment absolutely makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is slightly half-baked.

The goal is to be able to provide a public-interface.
Inside of that IIFE, you put together all of the pieces required for your interface.

You don't have to pass it back out through a return statement.

jQuery, for example, is built in the same way.
Instead of having a return statement:

```
var jQuery = (function () { return magic; }());
```

They manually set `window`'s `jQuery` (and `$`) properties from within the function, like so:

```
(function () { window["jQuery"] = magic; }());
```

Moreover, what's actually happening is a little bit different, still.
They're passing the `window` object into the IIFE's `window` parameter.
It doesn't have to be `window`, then.
It could be any previously-defined object you're extending, in theory.

```
var myApp = {};
(function (window, document) { window["jQuery"] = public_interface; }(myApp, document));
myApp.jQuery("...");
```

When building libraries similar to jQuery, you can do similar.
If you typically namespace any large libraries/applications (a good idea), you can shorten the name, internally, to make life easier.

Instead of:

var NAMESPACED_AWESOME_APP_OF_DOOM = {};
NAMESPACED_AWESOME_APP_OF_DOOM.module1 = {};

You can do something like:

```
(function (namespace) {

    var ns = {};
    window[namespace] = ns;

    ns.module1 = {};
    ns.module2 = {};
    ns.service1 = function () {};

}("NAMESPACED_AWESOME_APP_OF_DOOM"));
```

Then you can do all of your internal setup inside, and once your setup is complete, you can reference the application by name, in the global scope.

In other cases, you can create sandboxes for code, using closures in this way, with mediators to send messages back and forth between components.
Nicholas Zakas has a couple of good talks on this.

And lastly, sometimes you just want some work to get done, which is 100% irrelevant to the rest of your program, but still needs to get done, all the same (like doing compatibility-checks and tying the results to the DOM elements, a la Modernizr...  ...or setting cookies that just need to be there, or firing off calls to analytics software...  ...et cetera).

Comment: Thank you! You provided an answer to not just this question, but also to so many other questions I had while reading through some javascript codes on the Web :)

Answer (score 0):

In this specific instance, the anonymous function only serves to keep CarManager from being accessible elsewhere, i.e. entering into the global scope.

Also specific to this code instance, its entirely pointless. CarManager is not usable by any other code.

Looking at the link you provided in the comments, http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript

As far as I can tell, the entire section of code being documented, in addition to the CarManager.execute bit, will completely fail to work. Trying to define CarManager.execute = ... outside of the anonymous function will fail because CarManager doesn't exist.

Comment: Here's the web version of the section of the book: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm the OP. Based on the discussion above, and after trying to interpret what the author wanted to express, I'm coming to a conclusion that the following code might have been what the author wanted to express. At least for me this seems to make sense.

```
(function(){
    var CarManager = {
        requestInfo: function(model, id){
            /* blah blah */
        },
        buyVehicle: function(model, id){
            /* blah blah */
        },
        arrangeViewing: function( model, id ){
            /* blah blah */
        }
    };

    CarManager.execute = function(name){
        return CarManager[name] && CarManager[name].apply(CarManager, Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1));
    }

    return CarManager;
}());
```

Basically, I added the part where the anonymous function execution returns the CarManager object literal. Also, I placed the execute method before returning (Although I don't quite understand why it should be outside of the original CarManager object, other than potentially code readability) What do you think?

(By the way, the web version of the section of the book is here: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript )

Comment: 1. That `return` statement doesn't do you any good. If you don't have a variable assignment, there's nothing to catch the value of the return. ie: `var CarManager = (function(){...}());`. 2. The point of the demonstration in that section was to show how to provide a more-simplified public-interface, free from implementation details, by taking in "messages" which in this case are exactly the names of the methods. Not really simplifying much. In other cases, this can provide a huge benefit, if there's say a strategy-pattern inside the command-pattern. Check my given-answer for other valid output

Comment: Silly me! I meant to include var CarManager but totally forgot to. I'll just leave it as is, so as to not confuse any future readers about what you meant in your comment :)